# Ubuntu Deleted /var/logs

Tags: server, logs

Is there a way to restore /var/log ? I don't really care about past logs I at least need the dir structure so programs can write to their logs.

For example I went to start apache and it failed because it could not write /var/log/apache2/error.log

I ran sudo mkdir /var/log/apache2 tried again and apache loaded fine.

I am concerned about other programs that may not load because they do not have the ability to write to their log file. I happened to notice apache failing to load as I was working with it at the time. Had I not been updated my apache server this would have gone unknown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will be fine. If you have /var/log directories most programs can create a file. 
If you are having issues with another program check the main log for details.

Comment: Can most programs create the necessary *subdirectories* of `/var/log`? (Not all programs write log files *directly* in `/var/log`; some have their own subdirectories.) I think that's really what this question is asking.

Comment: @Eliah That is exactly what I'm getting at. I may not run into any problems. I just wanted to dbl check incase something fails and I am not aware of it